# Can I make class properties method parameters c#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to pass the names of a class's properties to parameters within a method. Currently I am duplicating the the method and changing the Sundries property and Customers[i] property. This method is required approximately 4 times so preferably doing it once would be much neater. I am then using a single modal pop up to load the different tables depending on what property of the customer class is called.

How do I make the Customer class properties available as a parameter in the BindList Method?

I have seen some posts on dictionary and func but unsure of how to use them.

*Note: static List Cust;

(In another method: Cust = CustomerList)

```
   public class Customer
    {
        public string CustName { get; set; }
        public string CustPhone { get; set; }
        public string CustAddress { get; set; }
        public string CustHistory { get; set; }
    }
```

*also: Parameters are just examples as I don't know what to put.

```
  public void BindLists(sundries.prop sundparm, Customer.prop custparm)
    {
        SundriesRepo sundries = new SundriesRepo();
        List<string> TempList = new List<string>();
        TempList = sundries.sundparm;

        lblEdit.Text = "History Edit";

        List<string> Used = new List<string>();
        List<string> NotUsed = new List<string>();

        if (Patients.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Cust.Count; i++)
            {
                string result = Cust[i].custparm;

                if (result != null)
                {
                    Used.Add(result);
                }
            }
            NotUsed = TempList.Except(Used).ToList();
        }

        listNotUsed.DataSource = NotUsed;
        listNotUsed.DataBind();
        listUsed.DataSource = Used;
        listUsed.DataBind();

        modPopExt1.Show();
    }
```

and the HTML is:

```
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="modPan" CssClass="modPan">
                    <div id="modPanHeader">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEdit"></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divfloat" class="divfloat">
                        <div id="divList" style="float: left" class="float">
                            <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listNotUsed" CssClass="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divPatient" style="float: right" class="float">
                            <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="listUsed" CssClass="listBox"></asp:ListBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divModPanBtnClose">
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="modPanBtnClose" Text="Close"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modPopExt1" PopupControlID="modPan" CancelControlID="modPanBtnClose" 
                    TargetControlID="lblEdit"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I can not write a parameter to be accepted at "String result = Cust[i].custparm;"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are asking if you can pass a class's properties as method parameters.

Of course, you can. 
Or simply pass/make the method expect a `Customer` instance.

```
var prop1 = null;
var prop2 =null;
var prop3 = null;
var prop4 = null;

//Which ever prop gets value

public void BindLists(string prop1 = null, string prop2= null, string prop3 =null, string prop4 =null)
{
  //check which ever is not null
  //Since you say one of them will be having the value.
  enter rest code here
}


//calling side
Customer cust = new Customer();
BindLists(prop1 = value, prop2 = value, prop3=value, prop4 = value) //default will be null
```

Comment: That would still require me to rewrite the method to change the cust property every time. I need to be able to change the class property via a method parameter.

Comment: cust is the instance which will be having all the properties values.

Comment: I want to make a list of the property values hence why I need to change the property not Cust. Cust.CustName, Cust.CustPhone etc

Comment: Once again you are not passing the class's properties as method parameters you are passing the whole class

Comment: Maybe you can make use of optional and named parameters.

Comment: can you give me an example please